# How get data by month using DBFlow android

Tags: android

I am new to `DBFlow`, Can anyone tell me the `select` query How get data by month using `DBFlow android`. The below code give error at where condition.

```
List<ExpenseAndIncome> expenseAndIncomes = newSelect().from(ExpenseAndIncome.class).where("strftime('%m', date)= ?",getMonthAsString(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH))).groupBy("date").queryList();

private String getMonthAsString(int month) {
    if (month > 0 && month < Constants.OCTOBER)
        return Constants.ZERO + (Integer.toString(month) + 1);
    return Integer.toString((month + 1));
}
```

Comment: post ExpenseAndIncome entity code.

Comment: What are you expecting `Zero + Integer.toString(month) + 1` to be? 091 for September?